# Vue panzoom align item center on zoomin to minimum

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am using vue2 vue-panzoom on an image.

I am trying to align  the image to the center when zoomedin to `1`.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue-panzoom-example-forked-czv8q6)

I tried below code. it gives me an error saying `panzoomInstance` is `undefined`.

```js
<template>
  <div id="app" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
    <div>
      <panZoom selector=".zoomable" id="panzoomContainer" :options="{minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 5}" @init="panCheck()">
        <div class="zoomable">
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568833450751-fba3c6b2d129?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="not-zoomable others">I am not zoomable</div>
      </panZoom>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods:{
    panCheck(panzoomInstance,id){
        if(panzoomInstance){    
            panzoomInstance.on('zoomend', function(e){
                if(panzoomInstance.getMaxZoom() === 1){
                    panzoomInstance.setTransformOrigin({x: 0.5, y: 0.5});
                }
            });
        }

    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Above code is not working.
I want to confirm `@init="panCheck()"` works on Vue2 `vue-panzoom@1.1.3`